# A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm working with javacv and when I try run my app with Android 6, it crashes.
The app only crash with android 6. I tested with android N, android 5 and android 4.4
the app crash when do a instance of `FFmpegFrameRecorder` class.
This is the code of my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new FFmpegFrameRecorder("", 320, 240, 1);
  }
}
```

this is my log error:

```
                                          --------- beginning of crash
05-16 14:46:15.845 6144-6144/com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 6144 (.pedro.ffmpeg30)
05-16 14:46:15.902 371-371/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-16 14:46:15.905 371-371/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/shamu/shamu:6.0.1/MMB29K/2419427:user/release-keys'
05-16 14:46:15.910 371-371/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
05-16 14:46:15.910 371-371/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
05-16 14:46:15.915 371-371/? A/DEBUG: pid: 6144, tid: 6144, name: .pedro.ffmpeg30  >>> com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30 <<<
05-16 14:46:15.915 371-371/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
05-16 14:46:15.912 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:525): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.912 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:526): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.912 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:527): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.912 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:528): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.922 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:529): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.922 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:530): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.922 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:531): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.922 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:532): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.922 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:533): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.922 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:534): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.922 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:535): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.922 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:536): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.940 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00000002  r2 b6811031  r3 a0f5de7c
05-16 14:46:15.940 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     r4 a0f59594  r5 b67c1a61  r6 b362f1a4  r7 00000001
05-16 14:46:15.940 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     r8 b6f4c6ec  r9 0000000b  sl b362f1a4  fp b6f452fc
05-16 14:46:15.941 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     ip fffffe8c  sp bea86820  lr a0efcec1  pc a0efe58a  cpsr 000d0030
05-16 14:46:15.932 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:537): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.964 371-371/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
05-16 14:46:15.965 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0001a58a  /data/data/com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30/cache/javacpp23106072121027/libc.so
05-16 14:46:15.965 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00016695  /data/data/com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30/cache/javacpp23106072121027/libc.so
05-16 14:46:15.965 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00002465  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfo13call_functionEPKcPFvvE+48)
05-16 14:46:15.965 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000252f  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfo10call_arrayEPKcPPFvvEjb+134)
05-16 14:46:15.965 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000026f5  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv+160)
05-16 14:46:15.965 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00006115  /system/bin/linker (__dl__Z9do_dlopenPKciPK17android_dlextinfo+224)
05-16 14:46:15.966 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00001c95  /system/bin/linker (__dl_dlopen+20)
05-16 14:46:15.966 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0025b13b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, _jobject*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+650)
05-16 14:46:15.966 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 002d13d7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime_nativeLoad(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+194)
05-16 14:46:15.962 371-371/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:538): avc: denied { search } for name="com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30" dev="dm-1" ino=742565 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-16 14:46:15.966 371-371/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 738b0105  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1ec9000)
05-16 14:46:16.339 863-6279/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.pedro.ffmpeg30/.MainActivity
05-16 14:46:16.339 371-371/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_07
05-16 14:46:16.339 371-371/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
```

I'm using the last version downloaded here:
http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|bytedeco

my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

  compile files('libs/javacv-1.2.jar')
  compile files('libs/javacpp-1.2.jar')
  compile files('libs/ffmpeg-3.0.2-1.2.jar')
  compile files('libs/ffmpeg-3.0.2-1.2-android-arm.jar')
}
```

Comment: Try to specify a valid filename to the constructor.

Comment: did you find any solution? i too facing the issue with latest javacv built. in android studio i debugged and i see app crashes with **A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 16282 (VideoCapturing)** on `Loader.load(avutil.class);`. No other further log or information. With previous version i was getting Unstatisfiedlinkerror.

Comment: I tried with a wowza url that work in android 5 and android 4.4 but the error persists. Could be a error in ffmpeg navite code?

Comment: Seems like a known bug: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/412  Please try to find the cause so we can fix this! Thanks